# Disable cache on back navigation ASP.NET Core for js script tags

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a script that is runtime generated, it contains translations for some labels. Its purpose is to expose translations to AngularJS.

```cs
app.MapWhen(current => current.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(path),
        mapped => mapped.UseMiddleware<ClientResourcesMiddleware>(options)
    );
```

The script is loaded in the layout:

```html
<script src="path" />
```

That will trigger the `ClientResourceMiddleware` and load the script in its response. That works perfectly.

The issue I'm having is when I switch the language (Profile page) and navigate back to the previous page. The script is not reloaded but cached, so I get the previous translations and not the new ones with the new language set.

I have tried:

- Setting the no-cache header in the response which I think should go in the request, but no idea how to set that in a script tag.
- Adding `asp-append-version="true"`

Looking at the network monitor I got a "Cached" tag. When I refresh the page then the new file is loaded.

Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: changing the implementation of what specifically is not an option, the implementation of the backend?

Comment: @Zinov changing the way that script is loaded using the middleware and the script tag. It's legacy code, so I was trying a "safe" approach. I'll clarify that.

Comment: @Zinov I better removed that, maybe something better can be done. However not sure how to proceed.

Comment: did you try to append to the get URL of the script any parameter you know is different all the time to force that load and check if that works?
But normally on the backend for those static files like the script you should ensure that you are telling the browser not to cache the resource. Something like this, but you will need to change the middleware code for that to include this type of statements
Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");

Comment: @Zinov yeah, I didn't think about manually adding the param. That made it. Thanks.
I added the language from the controller and appended it as a param in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Zinov Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137502503?noredirect=1) I implemented it the following way.

In order to let the browser that the resource changed, you can set manually a version property with the target language, so if it changes even if you navigate back, you'll get the desired version.

```
@{ var language = ViewBag["language"]; }

<script src="path?v=@language"></script>
```

In the middleware:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IRequestCultureFeature requestCultureFeature)
{
    string script = _cache.GetOrAddValue(
       $"ClientResources|{_options.ResourceType.FullName}|{requestCulture.Name}",
       () => CreateScript(requestCulture));

    context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(script, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Another option is to use `DateTime.Now.Ticks`, this will make the file to reload everytime.